# Why can't I access my session variables in PHP 7?

Tags: php, html, ubuntu, authentication, apache2

So I'm trying to create a login system, and I have tested that login.php is getting the POST data properly, I can print it out there. But what I've created should send back to index.php and find the session variable 'password' set and not empty, but it always prints the login page again.  Why can't I access my session variables?

my functions.php file:

```
<?php

function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'quassist_session';
    session_name($session_name);
    $secure = true;
    $httponly = true;
    if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
        header("Location: ../error.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session (ini_set)");
        exit();
    }
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);
    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id(true);
}

function sec_session_logout() {
    $_SESSION = array();
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000,
        $params["path"], $params["domain"],
        $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);
    session_destroy();
}

?>
```

my login.php file:

```
<?php

include_once 'functions.php';

sec_session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['formuser'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['formpass'];
header("Location: index.php"); /* Redirect browser */
exit();

?>
```

my index.php file:

```
<?php
include_once("functions.php");
sec_session_start();

    echo "<html>";
    echo "<head>";
    echo "<title>Login</title>";
    echo "<link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>";
    echo "</head>";
    echo "<body>";

if(isset($_SESSION['password']) && !empty($_SESSION['password'])) {
    // user entered password
    echo $_SESSION['username'] . "<br>" . $_SESSION['password'];
    // logout
    // sec_session_logout();
} else {
    echo "<div class='login-page'>";
    echo "<div class='form'>";
    echo "<form class='login-form' action='http://www.quassist.com/login.php' method='post'/>";
    echo "<input name='formuser' type='text' placeholder='username'/>";
    echo "<input name='formpass' type='password' placeholder='password'/>";
    echo "<button type='submit' value='Submit'>login</button>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
}

    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and if you happen to be using a mysql database; make sure you're not using `mysql_`, since that is no longer supported in php 7.

Comment: A couple of notes: 1. Password does not belong inside the session, ever. 2. Mixing HTML with PHP this way is very old school and not very good. You should look into something like Twig for templating and create a route-based MVC-ish pattern with something like Slim or Laravel. 3. It looks like you are logging yourself out if the password is set in index.php, which would explain why you always end up logged out at the bottom. session_destroy() invalidates the session.

Comment: thats a lot of "extra" code for starting a session

Comment: the extra code is for starting a SECURE session per [http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL)

Comment: You don't need to regenerate the session ID each time you start it. You also don't need to name it anything particular or modify ini settings inline. You should modify the ini file itself instead.

Comment: @nickdnk 1. yes i know, I'm just trying to get the hang of it 2. I have no idea what any of those things are and want to learn a simple php/html implementation 3. the logout part is only called if the if statement evaluates to true which it never does. I always return to the login page (else)

Comment: and yet you pass the password unencrypted over the interwerb by not using ssl

Comment: @nogad this is in a very beginning stage. I will implement TLS when it gets nearer production. I would appreciate some help not pointing out unrelated mistakes (which I haven't even tackled yet)

Comment: You are setting the password variable in login, then checking if it IS set and NOT empty (both true) in which case you log out, which, again, explains why you always end up logged out in the end.

Comment: unrelated? you tell the code to only use ssl and you dont have sll implemented, think about that

Comment: @nickdnk even if i remove the logging out it does the same.  the log out function doesn't as yet contain anything to redirect or refresh.

Comment: He tells it to only use HTTP, not SSL. While I agree with you, SSL has nothing to do with his problem.

Comment: @nogad i started working on this today. I know that I'll have to implement TLS/HTTPS and I will, I just haven't done that yet. Thank you but that isn't the question.

Comment: @nickdnk no read the code again

Comment: You don't need to refresh to log out. You POST to login, set password, then redirect to index. Index checks if password is set, then logs out if so? It makes no sense.

Comment: Ah, yes, the secure cookie flag. Remove that if you are not currently using SSL.

Comment: its just a test!!! OMG!!! I'll comment out the log out!!! SAME QUESTION

Comment: Remove the secure cookie flag, clear browser cache then try again. If you are setting a secure cookie and not using SSL, your browser will not send the cookie to the redirect using HTTP. Also, stop yelling and omit silly code if you don't want people to comment on it.

Comment: test or not, the code will make it fail. The session id will not be sent in the cookie, as it its not using ssl, so your sessions will fail, that's why you are asking for help? Some people can't be helped i guess.

Comment: @nickdnk it wasn't silly. it actually had a function. I had to log out somewhere so I could test it multiple times, anyone think of that? if i had no logout, it wouldn't ever go back to the login page

Comment: Yes, it's called "to clear cookies" and is built into your browser. Or you could create a logout.php that just calls session_destroy(). You don't need to implement silly code and include it as part of your question if it has nothing to do with the question. Now, remove the secure flag as we told you twice.

Comment: i just changed the $secure and it works perfectly, WITH the logout, i hit refresh and it goes back to the login page. EXACTLY what i was testing and trying to do. Thank you for the help, even if it was within a bunch of crap.

Comment: Next time, clean up your code and leave in the things relevant to your question. You asked specifically why it printed false - true at the bottom, which it would do any way you spin it WITH the logout implemented, which is why I commented on it.

Comment: well hopefully you can be less condescending to the free help next time you ask :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

```
$secure = true;
```

can only be used if you're using TLS/HTTPS. Otherwise it will keep the cookies from working.

Answer (score -1):

You must implement session_start function at the first line of php code.